# Storing data in minio (S3 like system)

Tags: php, symfony, akeneo

I've been trying to get Akeneo to store all files in on an object storage server (minIO) I've followed the guide here: https://docs.akeneo.com/4.0/manipulate_pim_data/store_assets_externally.html as that is using aws-sdk-php I thought i could do it like this:

in config/services/prod/storage.yml i've added

```
services:
    Aws\S3\S3Client:
        arguments:
            -
                version: 'latest'
                region: 'us-east-1'
                endpoint: '<address to minio server>'
                use_path_style_endpoint: true
                credentials:
                    key: "<my key>"
                    secret: "<My secrete>"
```

And this is how config/packages/prod/oneup_flysystem.yml looks

```
oneup_flysystem:
    adapters:
        asset_storage_adapter:
            awss3v3:
                client: 'Aws\S3\S3Client'
                bucket: '<my-bucket>'
        catalog_storage_adapter:
            awss3v3:
                client: 'Aws\S3\S3Client'
                bucket: '<my-bucket>'
        jobs_storage_adapter:
            local:
                directory: '%kernel.project_dir%/var/file_storage/jobs'
        archivist_adapter:
            local:
                directory: '%kernel.project_dir%/var/file_storage/archive'
```

I've tested this configurations with aws-s3-php directly and than i get it to work.

The strange thing for me is that i don't even get an error, it just stores the files on the akeneo server instead. Is it something i have to do to make Akeneo "take" the configuration ?

below are my system information

```
Edition CE
Version 4.0.39
Environment prod
Install time    2020-07-08T23:24:47+0200
Server version  Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu)
Number of channels  1
Number of locales   1
Number of products  1
Number of product models    0
Number of variant products  0
Number of families  1
Number of attributes    2
Number of users 1
Number of categories    1
Number of category trees    1
Max number of categories in one category    0
Max number of category levels   0
Number of product values    0
Average number of product values by product 0
Average number of potential product values by family    2
Max number of potential product values by family    2
Associated email domains    ljusihus.se
Number of scopable attributes   0
Number of localizable attributes    0
Number of localizable and scopable attributes   0
Number of attributes useable as grid filter 1
Average percentage of scopable attributes per family (%)    0
Average percentage of localizable attributes per family (%) 0
Average percentage of localizable and scopable attributes per family (%)    0
Average number of attributes per family 2
OS version  Linux PIM 4.15.18-25-pve #1 SMP PVE 4.15.18-53 (Wed, 05 Feb 2020 11:58:15 +0100) x86_64
PHP version 7.3.19-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1
MySQL version   8.0.20
PHP extensions  Core
date
libxml
openssl
pcre
zlib
filter
hash
Reflection
SPL
sodium
session
standard
cgi-fcgi
mysqlnd
PDO
xml
apcu
bcmath
bz2
calendar
ctype
curl
dom
mbstring
fileinfo
ftp
gd
gettext
iconv
imagick
intl
json
exif
mysqli
pdo_mysql
apc
posix
radius
readline
shmop
SimpleXML
sockets
sysvmsg
sysvsem
sysvshm
tokenizer
wddx
xmlreader
xmlwriter
xsl
zip
Phar
Zend OPcache
xdebug
Registered bundles  Akeneo\Channel\Bundle\AkeneoChannelBundle
Akeneo\Connectivity\Connection\Infrastructure\Symfony\AkeneoConnectivityConnectionBundle
Akeneo\Pim\Enrichment\Bundle\AkeneoPimEnrichmentBundle
Akeneo\Pim\Structure\Bundle\AkeneoPimStructureBundle
Akeneo\Platform\Bundle\AnalyticsBundle\PimAnalyticsBundle
Akeneo\Platform\Bundle\CatalogVolumeMonitoringBundle\PimCatalogVolumeMonitoringBundle
Akeneo\Platform\Bundle\DashboardBundle\PimDashboardBundle
Akeneo\Platform\Bundle\ImportExportBundle\PimImportExportBundle
Akeneo\Platform\Bundle\InstallerBundle\PimInstallerBundle
Akeneo\Platform\Bundle\NotificationBundle\PimNotificationBundle
Akeneo\Platform\Bundle\UIBundle\PimUIBundle
Akeneo\Tool\Bundle\ApiBundle\PimApiBundle
Akeneo\Tool\Bundle\BatchBundle\AkeneoBatchBundle
Akeneo\Tool\Bundle\BatchQueueBundle\AkeneoBatchQueueBundle
Akeneo\Tool\Bundle\ClassificationBundle\AkeneoClassificationBundle
Akeneo\Tool\Bundle\ConnectorBundle\PimConnectorBundle
Akeneo\Tool\Bundle\ElasticsearchBundle\AkeneoElasticsearchBundle
Akeneo\Tool\Bundle\FileStorageBundle\AkeneoFileStorageBundle
Akeneo\Tool\Bundle\MeasureBundle\AkeneoMeasureBundle
Akeneo\Tool\Bundle\StorageUtilsBundle\AkeneoStorageUtilsBundle
Akeneo\Tool\Bundle\VersioningBundle\AkeneoVersioningBundle
Akeneo\UserManagement\Bundle\PimUserBundle
Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\DoctrineBundle
Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineCacheBundle\DoctrineCacheBundle
Doctrine\Bundle\FixturesBundle\DoctrineFixturesBundle
Doctrine\Bundle\MigrationsBundle\DoctrineMigrationsBundle
FOS\JsRoutingBundle\FOSJsRoutingBundle
FOS\OAuthServerBundle\FOSOAuthServerBundle
FOS\RestBundle\FOSRestBundle
Liip\ImagineBundle\LiipImagineBundle
Oneup\FlysystemBundle\OneupFlysystemBundle
Oro\Bundle\ConfigBundle\OroConfigBundle
Oro\Bundle\DataGridBundle\OroDataGridBundle
Oro\Bundle\FilterBundle\OroFilterBundle
Oro\Bundle\PimDataGridBundle\PimDataGridBundle
Oro\Bundle\PimFilterBundle\PimFilterBundle
Oro\Bundle\SecurityBundle\OroSecurityBundle
Oro\Bundle\TranslationBundle\OroTranslationBundle
Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\SensioFrameworkExtraBundle
Symfony\Bundle\AclBundle\AclBundle
Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\FrameworkBundle
Symfony\Bundle\MonologBundle\MonologBundle
Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\SecurityBundle
Symfony\Bundle\SwiftmailerBundle\SwiftmailerBundle
Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\TwigBundle
```